# Передача функции в компонент React Native

Tags: react-native

Есть файл с компонентом
file1.tsx

```
    return (
    <>
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.droidSafeArea}/>
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <CustomHeader title='Сканер' navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={this.onBarCodeRead}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
      />
      {this.renderMessage()}
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
  </>
);
```

Как мне передать {this.renderMessage()} в другой файл с компонентом?

```
    render(){
    return(
        <View>
            {/* <Text {...this.props}>Helli, {this.props.lol}</Text> */}
    <Text>{Функция из file1.tsx}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class App {
 renderMessage = () => <View />

 render() {
  return (
   <File1>
   {this.renderMessage()}
   </File1>
  );
 }
}

class File1 {

 render() {
  return (
   <View>
    {this.props.children}
   </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]